# Laravel app routes not working when using domain name (fine with IP address) on AWS Lightsail

Tags: nginx, php, ssl, laravel, amazon-lightsail

I am running a Laravel 10.x application on an Amazon Lightsail server here - 18.134.48.92

Currently when browsing to http://18.134.48.92/login I am correctly shown the login page (I am using Laravel Breeze) which works fine and as expected. However I have setup the domain pro-clubs.app and when I navigate to https://pro-clubs.app/login I do not see the expected login page but a "404 Not Found" nginx error.

I am using Amazon Lightsail which uses the NGINX open source packaged by Bitnami for AWS Cloud here https://docs.bitnami.com/aws/infrastructure/nginx/

I appear to have FOUR server blocks for this app which are as follows

```
https-proclubs-https-server-block.conf
https-proclubs-server-block.conf
proclubs-https-server-block.conf
proclubs-server-block.conf
```

Both `https-proclubs-https-server-block.conf` & `https-proclubs-server-block.conf` are empty files for some reason, however the latter two both contain the following:

proclubs-https-server-block.conf

```
 server {
      # Port to listen on, can also be set in IP:PORT format
      listen 443 ssl default_server;
      root /opt/bitnami/projects/proclubs/public;
      # Catch-all server block
      # See: https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/server_names.html#miscellaneous_names
      server_name pro-clubs.app www.pro-clubs.app;
      ssl_certificate      /opt/bitnami/nginx/conf/pro-clubs.app.crt;
      ssl_certificate_key  /opt/bitnami/nginx/conf/pro-clubs.app.key;
      include  "/opt/bitnami/nginx/conf/bitnami/*.conf";
  }
```

proclubs-server-block.conf

```
 server {
      # Port to listen on, can also be set in IP:PORT format
      listen 80 default_server;
      root /opt/bitnami/projects/proclubs/public;
      index index.php index.html;

      charset utf-8;

      location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
      }

      location ~ /\.(?!well-known).* {
        deny all;
      }

      # Catch-all server block
      # See: https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/server_names.html#miscellaneous_names
      server_name pro-clubs.app www.pro-clubs.app;
      ssl_certificate      /opt/bitnami/nginx/conf/pro-clubs.app.crt;
      ssl_certificate_key  /opt/bitnami/nginx/conf/pro-clubs.app.key;
      include  "/opt/bitnami/nginx/conf/bitnami/*.conf";
  }
```

What changes should I make so that my application routes are working when using the SSL domains like https://pro-clubs.app/dashboard for instance

**Expected outcome:**

When navigating to https://pro-clubs.app/login I see the Laravel login page

**Actual outcome:**

When navigating to https://pro-clubs.app/login I see an "404 Not Found" nginx error

Comment: 2 things: 1) `listen 443 ssl default_server;` strange that it listens to 'default_server'? 2) in nginx configs you can turn on 'error_log' where it shows you the actual error why it's giving you the nginx 404 error

Comment: I've used bncert a tool for generating SSL certificates and I believes that modifies the files (as it creates a backup of the old file) - will check the error log

Answer (score 1):

Rookie mistake..
For some reason the following lines were present in the one conf but not the https one.. added these and it seems to work now

```
      index index.php index.html;

      charset utf-8;

      location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
      }

      location ~ /\.(?!well-known).* {
        deny all;
      }
```